# Why am I losing 1 reputation every day?

Tags: support, reputation

I've been losing 1 reputation daily for the past several day, and I'm not getting any notifications for it. My reputation went from 2,322 to 2,319 over the last 3 days.

[image: Screenshot]

Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that screenshot doesn't help. We need to see your [reputation tab, by time](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3196723/govind-singh-nagarkoti?tab=reputation&sort=time).

Comment: And when taking the screenshot, please check the "view deleted posts" checkbox.

Comment: You have probably posted answers (and received upvotes on those answers) to poor-quality questions that have been deleted. Consider not answering bad questions that are likely to be deleted.

Comment: I see no evidence that you've been "losing 1 reputation a day". Also, you might want to consider cropping out your email address from your screenshots in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably, you have downvoted some answers. Downvoting an answer costs 1 reputation point.

It could also be that a post, on which you suggested an edit, is deleted. Then you lose the 2 points which you earned from the suggested edit. Go to your "reputation" tab and check the "view deleted posts" checkbox, then you can see if this happened.

Comment: oops ,yes some posts are removed, but i didn't get notifocations for it

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti, we don't receive notifications about lost points.